R : Suggests vs Depends for package called in vignettes and/or examples only
From a  package I'm currently developing, I'm using a package only in the vignette or examples, to get data and make some runnable examples.
library(STexampleData)
spe <- Visium_humanDLPFC()

I was wondering if I should use it in Imports or Suggests.
Initially the package was in Imports but then the R CMD check complained because @import STexampleData was not declared anywhere.
This package is only involved in the @examples part.
I was wondering if I shoud declare in an @import even if it's only called in the example.

Read WRE. The ‘Suggests’ field uses the same syntax as ‘Depends’ and lists packages that are not necessarily needed. This includes packages used only in examples, tests or vignettes ...

WRE="Writing R Extensions". The official documentation from the R project on writing packages.
